# Adding "recommended reading" in Developer Story isn't as quick as it was in the old Jobs CV

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

Back in the old days, before Developer Story, we had the Jobs CV feature. There, I seem to remember that it was possible to add links to blog posts or books you've read, and it would automatically fill in the title, author and short description etc.

These days, in Developer Story (in "Recommended reading"), one has to manually fill all this in and it makes me sad.

Any chance of getting the old, helpful & time saving feature back please?

[image: no freehand red circles add new reading]

Comment: Great comment Keith. Thanks for sharing. We'll look into this.